# If $f$ is a prime polynomial, then $f$ and $f'$ have no common root

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Problem:** If $f$ is a prime polynomial from $\mathbb Q[x]$, then $f$ and $f'$ have no common root.

**My attempt:** Suppose $f$ and $f'$ have the root $c$ in common. Divide $f$ by $f'$ to get $f = f'\cdot q + r$. Then $r = f - f'\cdot q$ and so $r(c) = 0$.

**Question:** I know that the degree of $r$ is less than that of $f$, but have I found a contradiction somehow?  I just don't see it.

Comment: What you've done is the first step of the Euclidean algorithm.  That's a hint how to continue.

Comment: The difference between this question and the link is that this is a prime polynomial.

Comment: By the linked dupe, if $f,f'$ had a common root $r$ then $\,f = (x-r)^2 g,\,$ which is reducible so not prime.

Comment: @BillDubuque Should I assume that the root is in $\mathbb Q$ as well?